# How to convert the images of kafka confluent from Debian:Jessie to CentOS7

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, dockerfile, confluent-platform

The current images of confluent Kafka for Kafka-connect, schema-registry, KSQL are in Debian: Jessie in docker hub. How can I convert them into the CentOS base image?

[This Github issue link](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/issues/677) has one procedure to use `make build-debian` and since the `base` folder has `Dockerfile.rpm` that uses `From centos` to create a base image of `centos` but the other services do not have any. So the question coming to me is -

the `base` part has Dockerfile.rpm that uses `From centos:centos7`. The other images, e.g. Kafka-connect, are getting build from the docker hub `confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect` that uses Debian: Jessie as its base. Is there any way to convert this into centos?

Does docker provide an option to create an image of a different base OS from one existing image?

**I am new to docker, so some of the questions can be very basic.**

Comment: You can't do this (in much the same way as you'd have to reinstall a full system from scratch to change its Linux distribution).  Is there a reason you need to?  From an operator point of view it usually doesn't matter what base image a Docker image uses.

Comment: We have a custom service that is only centos compatible. So I was looking if  we can build confluent Kafka services image in centos.

Comment: Run it in its own container `FROM centos:7`.  It would connect to Kafka as a network service; it doesn't really care what distribution the Confluent images or running.